# JAXB Classes from Schema : how do I generate a java class containing elements from multiple schemas?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have 3 XML schemas:

- **A.xsd** (provided to me and cannot be modified)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://readonly.com/cantChangeXsd" targetNamespace="http://readonly.com/cantChangeXsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="3">
  <xs:element name="RootElement" nillable="false">
      <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="ElementA" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="ElementA" nillable="false">
      <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Element exists in original schema provided to me</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="attribute1" use="optional">
              <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>The first attribute</xs:documentation>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                      <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
          <xs:attribute name="attribute2" use="optional">
              <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>The second attribute</xs:documentation>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  ```
- **B.xsd** (imports **A.xsd** and defines another complex type specific to my use-case)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sat="http://satbot.com/example" xmlns:ven="http://readonly.com/cantChangeXsd" targetNamespace="http://satbot.com/example" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2.2">
  <!--************************************************************************************************-->
  <xsd:import namespace="http://readonly.com/cantChangeXsd" schemaLocation="A.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="ElementBType">
      <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="ElementBDateTime" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  ```
- **C.xsd** (includes **B.xsd** and adds the new element that was defined to the schema)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://satbot.com/example" targetNamespace="http://satbot.com/example" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2.2">
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="B.xsd"/>
  <xsd:element name="ElementB" type="ElementBType" nillable="false">
      <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation>Element that is added for my use-case</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
  </xsd:element>
  ```

I've used the following command to generate java classes from these schemas:

```
xjc C.xsd -p com.satbot.xml
```

I am trying to generate JAXB classes from Schema and I select **C.xsd** as the source. The plan is to unmarshall from **C.xml** shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://readonly.com/cantChangeXsd" xmlns:sat="http://satbot.com/example" xsi:schemaLocation="C.xsd">
    <ElementA attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2"/>
    <sat:ElementB>
        <sat:ElementBDateTime>2017-07-21T00:00:00Z</sat:ElementBDateTime>
    </sat:ElementB>
</RootElement>
```

All complex types are successfully generated in separate java classes, however I can't see any way of accessing the contents of ***ElementB*** from an instance of the ***RootElement*** class. How can I access ***ElementB***?

The generated classes are included below:

ElementA.java

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.8-b130911.1802 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2017.07.24 at 12:14:55 PM AEST 
//


package com.satbot.xml;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element ref="{http://readonly.com/cantChangeXsd}ElementA" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;any processContents='lax' namespace='##other' minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "elementA",
    "any"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "RootElement")
public class RootElement {

    @XmlElement(name = "ElementA")
    protected ElementA elementA;
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected Object any;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the elementA property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link ElementA }
     *     
     */
    public ElementA getElementA() {
        return elementA;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the elementA property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link ElementA }
     *     
     */
    public void setElementA(ElementA value) {
        this.elementA = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the any property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Object }
     *     {@link Element }
     *     
     */
    public Object getAny() {
        return any;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the any property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Object }
     *     {@link Element }
     *     
     */
    public void setAny(Object value) {
        this.any = value;
    }

}
```

ElementBType.java

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.8-b130911.1802 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2017.07.20 at 05:40:04 PM AEST 
//


package com.satbot.xml;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;


/**
 * <p>Java class for ElementBType complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="ElementBType">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="ElementBDateTime" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}dateTime"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ElementBType", namespace = "http://satbot.com/example", propOrder = {
    "elementBDateTime"
})
public class ElementBType {

    @XmlElement(name = "ElementBDateTime", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar elementBDateTime;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the elementBDateTime property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getElementBDateTime() {
        return elementBDateTime;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the elementBDateTime property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public void setElementBDateTime(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.elementBDateTime = value;
    }

}
```

ObjectFactory.java

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.8-b130911.1802 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2017.07.20 at 05:40:04 PM AEST 
//


package com.satbot.xml;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


/**
 * This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * generated in the com.satbot.xml package. 
 * <p>An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically 
 * construct new instances of the Java representation 
 * for XML content. The Java representation of XML 
 * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
 * and classes representing the binding of schema 
 * type definitions, element declarations and model 
 * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are 
 * provided in this class.
 * 
 */
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _ElementB_QNAME = new QName("http://satbot.com/example", "ElementB");

    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: com.satbot.xml
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link ElementBType }
     * 
     */
    public ElementBType createElementBType() {
        return new ElementBType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link RootElement }
     * 
     */
    public RootElement createRootElement() {
        return new RootElement();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link ElementA }
     * 
     */
    public ElementA createElementA() {
        return new ElementA();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ElementBType }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://satbot.com/example", name = "ElementB")
    public JAXBElement<ElementBType> createElementB(ElementBType value) {
        return new JAXBElement<ElementBType>(_ElementB_QNAME, ElementBType.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

package-info.java

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.8-b130911.1802 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2017.07.20 at 05:40:04 PM AEST 
//

@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://readonly.com/cantChangeXsd", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.satbot.xml;
```

RootElement.java

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.8-b130911.1802 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2017.07.20 at 05:40:04 PM AEST 
//


package com.satbot.xml;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element ref="{http://readonly.com/cantChangeXsd}ElementA" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "elementA"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "RootElement")
public class RootElement {

    @XmlElement(name = "ElementA")
    protected ElementA elementA;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the elementA property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link ElementA }
     *     
     */
    public ElementA getElementA() {
        return elementA;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the elementA property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link ElementA }
     *     
     */
    public void setElementA(ElementA value) {
        this.elementA = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: "there is no class that I can use as a single root..." - What do you mean exactly? Do you not know what the root element is in B.xml? Have you tried anything; if yes, show your code, and did you get an error? What is the exact error message?

Comment: @Jesper thanks for the suggestion, I added more info to the question. I didn't get any error messages, just new to this and seem to be missing something about how to access all of the elements.

Comment: What exactly did you expect - that `RootElement` would contain an `ElementB`? That's not what the XSDs say. In A.xsd, it is defined that `RootElement` contains an `ElementA`. Nothing there says that it can contain an `ElementB`, so the generated class for `RootElement` does not have a field of type `ElementB` and does not refer to `ElementBType` in any way. If you cannot modify A.xsd, then there is no way to change `RootElement` so that it can contain an `ElementB`.

Comment: @Jesper In that case is there any way to access ElementB? Keep in mind I'll have C.xml that contains both ElementA and ElementB which should be valid according to C.xsd

Comment: Where exactly in the tree structure is ElementB in C.xml / what is the root element in C.xml? If it is RootElement as defined in A.xsd and it contains ElementB (next to ElementA) then it does not conform to C.xsd - you're not allowed to put anything in RootElement that is not supposed to be there according to the XSD.

Comment: I've added a C.xml example to the question. How does it not conform to C.xsd? Where else could ElementB go?

Comment: @Jesper I forgot to add a line that exists in the A.xsd. C.xml is now valid according to C.xsd (because A.xsd has the any element line). However I'm still not sure how to access ElementB in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the `XmlRootElement` annotation to **ElementB.java** as follows:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ElementBType", namespace = "http://satbot.com/example", propOrder = {
    "elementBDateTime"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ElementB")
public class ElementBType {

//ElementB definition...

}
```

and then unmarshall the XML into the `RootElement` class like so:

```
static RootElement unmarshallXml(File xmlFile) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootElement.class, ElementBType.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    RootElement rootElement = (RootElement) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
    return rootElement;
}
```

Finally I could access `ElementB` using the following getter defined in **RootElement.java**:

```
public ElementB getElementB() {
    return (ElementB) getAny();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you initially left out of A.xsd (the `<xs:any>`) is very important! Otherwise it would not have been valid for `RootElement` to contain `ElementB`. Also, when you add this, `xjc` will generate another field named `any` in the class for `RootElement`, of type `Object`, along with a `getAny` and `setAny` method. It's through this field that you can get the `ElementB`. Example:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootElement.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

RootElement root;
try (InputStream in = SatBot.class.getResourceAsStream("/C.xml")) {
    root = (RootElement) unmarshaller.unmarshal(in);
}

// Get ElementB from the field 'any' in RootElement
JAXBElement<ElementBType> jaxbElement = (JAXBElement<ElementBType>) root.getAny();
ElementBType elementB = jaxbElement.getValue();

System.out.println(elementB.getElementBDateTime());
```

Comment: With your approach I'm getting the following exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement